# can I use CTE this way?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

Working to refactor a stored procedure to convert from heavy SQLXML statements to plain SQL resultset... it's been difficult..

Thinking to define multiple CTE tables, each reference the previous one, like this:

```
;WITH CTE1(column1)
as (....)
CTE2(column2)
as (select column2,... 
    inner join (select ... 
        group by column3 
        having column3 in (select column1 from CTE1))
CTE3
as (select ... 
    inner join (select ... 
        group by column4, column5
        having column4 in (select column1 from CTE1)
          and column5 in (select column2 from CTE2)
    )
select *
from CTE1, CTE2, CTE3
```

Although the final select does not join each other, but can I still expect the correct resultset

Comment: You can chain CTE statements within the same statement as you suggested, but definitely wouldn't recommend it as it could cause very heavy impact on your database server for larger servers. You should consider staging or temp tables if possible based on your result set sizes. Your final statement will be a large cartesian product - couldn't you union them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use comma after each CTE like below:

```
;WITH CTE1(column1)
as (....)
,
CTE2(column2)
as (select column2,... 
    inner join (select ... 
        group by column3 
        having column3 in (select column1 from CTE1))
,
CTE3
as (select ... 
    inner join (select ... 
        group by column4, column5
        having column4 in (select column1 from CTE1)
          and column5 in (select column2 from CTE2)
    )
select *
from CTE1, CTE2, CTE3
```